# Remove word from div element

Tags: javascript, html, compare

I am creating an operating system environment which of coerce has desktop icons. These icons are are identified with the id of a number and icon label by its number and the value text.

When I right click on any icon my context menu appears, this picks up the id of the icon clicked on and adds the name of the icon and the word icon to the top of the menu so you can identify which icon is clicked.

When I click a link within the menu like open, I need to re use the menu header text minus the word icon so I can relocate this icon by its label to perform the task.

Here's what I have for locating the icon.

```
function LocateIcon(Icon) 
{
if (Icon <= document.getElementById('IconsTotal').innerHTML)
{
if (document.getElementById('WI'+Icon+'Text').innerHTML == document.getElementById('ContextMenuStatus').innerText)
{
return Icon;
} else {
LocateIcon(+Icon +1);
}
} else {
AlertBox('No match found.');
}
}
```

You can see an example here: http://www.stepnageos.com

I have this working by updating the the code when you mouse over an icon. My problem is that when the menu is active, placing the mouse over another icon changes the value so the options will not relate to the original icon.

This is why i need to use the value from the open menu.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need, then edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and **your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**, so we have the information we need to be able to can help.

Comment: Please take a look at how to include the relevant code in an [example that is **minimal and reproducible**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run to see the problem, and edit your question to add it. For example we need to see an example of the HTML that this is trying to work on to understand what it's trying to do (not *all* of the HTML, just the minimal amount needed to show the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can import jQuery in your HTML and use `$("div").replaceWith("about")`, which replaces the words with about.

```js
$("div").replaceWith("about")
```

```html
<div>about icon</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit an element's **innerHTML** by referencing the element and directly setting the property to the new text, like this:

```
let div = document.getElementById('container');

div.innerHTML = 'About';
```

Here's a quick [repl.it](https://repl.it/@P0WRFULCOW89/Stepnage)!

Comment: That doesn’t really answer the question, the OP needs to *get* the innerText of a specific element first - not set it to a fixed value.

Comment: I really don't need to update anything. First I update an element by the way of mouse over for visual purposes, then I use that value for use with another script such as my menu. When the mouse is remover or no longer hovering over an element, the element i updated for visual purposes is also changed

What I need to do is re use the visual element that gets updated to the menu, to compare with the original.

Sounds complicated but i know it can be done. Take a look at my work and you will have more of an understanding as to what i am trying to achieve.